# Create a SilverStripe theme with Reactjs

Tags: php, reactjs, silverstripe

I am thinking on using **SilverStripe** as a CMS for a website I'm coding. I want to use **ReactJS** for the theme of the frontend's UI. I can't find any information on this except from [this](https://www.google.com/url?q=https://www.silverstripe.org/au/blog/cutting-through-the-noise-why-silverstripe-4-will-use-reactjs/&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwiziMT9m5DSAhVlBsAKHSYmDqYQFggHMAE&client=internal-uds-cse&usg=AFQjCNEIQcXnm0XrSztNxArd-Gbc8pPVJw), but that only states that they are integrating it and nothing else. Have also looked into [this](https://github.com/unclecheese/silverstripe-kickassets) but that's a backend UI extension.

Has anybody tried it out?

Comment: This sort of question is off topic for Stackoverflow - you'd have better luck on the SilverStripe Forums or in the community Slack channel :)

Comment: Unfortunately, questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic here. However, you may find better luck [SoftwareRecs.SE](//softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tour). Remember to read [their question requirements](//softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as they are more strict than this site.

Comment: Reformulated the questions to make it compliant with Stack Overflow's requirements

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SilverStripe makes no assumptions or impositions on what you do with your frontend. You're free to use any framework and/or toolchain you like. For some good examples of React/Webpack with in a SilverStripe theme, check out:

https://github.com/stevie-mayhew/silverstripe-redux-example

Or for just a basic webpack workflow:

https://github.com/unclecheese/silverstripe-webpack-starter

Comment: just what I needed! thanks for sharing!